# ng-model value of input text box is undefined inside angularjs controller when set dynamically through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In my HTML Page i am setting an input text box value not by typing but through JavaScript and then when I am fetching that value using AngularJS inside the controller using scope, then it's showing undefined....

Below is my code:-->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form id="someForm" name="someForm">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
    Last Name:  <input type="text" id="lname" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
   <input id="getUser" type="submit" ng-click="getUserName(user)" value="Get User" />
   <button ng-click="resetForm(user)">RESET</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
$('#getUser').on('click', function(){
  //$("getUser").on('click', function(){
     //alert("First Name "+$("#fname").val());
     $("#lname").val($("#fname").val());
     alert("Last Name set to "+$("#lname").val());
 // });
});

</script>
<script>
//angular.element(document).ready(function () {});
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.getUserName = function(user)
{

     alert("Last Name in Angular Controller: "+$scope.user.lastname)     

}
$scope.resetForm = function(user) {
      //Even when you use form = {} it does not work
      angular.copy({},user);
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After clicking Get User Button, first the lastname field value is set through JQuery then AngularJS controller is called in which the ng-model value is undefined. I am unable to understand this. What is the solution or workaround for this type of scenario where the input text field value is set dynamically through JavaScript or JQuery and fetched and used using AngularJS Model and Controller.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, But still getting undefined. See my comment below..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo at ng-model="user.lasttname"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form id="someForm" name="someForm">
    First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change'}" />
    Last Name:  <input type="text" id="lname" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'change blur'}" />
   <input id="getUser" type="button" ng-click="getUserName(user)" value="Get User" />
   <input id="getUser2" type="button" ng-click="getUserName(user)" value="Get User" />
   <button ng-click="resetForm(user)">RESET</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
$('#getUser').on('click', function(){
     var element = angular.element($('#someForm'));
     element.scope().user.lastname = $("#fname").val();  
});

</script>
<script>
//angular.element(document).ready(function () {});
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.user = {};

$scope.getUserName = function()
{
    console.log("User: "+ JSON.stringify($scope.user));
     alert("Last Name in Angular Controller: "+$scope.user.lastname)     

}
$scope.resetForm = function(user) {
      //Even when you use form = {} it does not work
//      angular.copy({},user);
    }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: event after correcting typo, I am getting undefined for $scope.user.lastname

Comment: Sure.  So, a few different ways you can accomplish this.  I'll modify the code above with an example

Comment: thanks for the code, it works, but actually the JQuery code written above under first script tag is a sample one. In actual scenario this JQuery code which dynamically changes text box is not with us i.e. with some other client (3rd Party), so is there any way on our side ( i.e. in our AngularJS Code), where we can fetch that changed Text box value.

Comment: Since you are already using jquery, you could bind to the change event of the text box that will be changed by the 3rd party code using jquery, then within that event handler user the code provided above to affect your angular model.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in angularjs code:-

```
<script>
//angular.element(document).ready(function () {});
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {}; // Initiate this
    $scope.getUserName = function(user)
    {
        alert("Last Name in Angular Controller: "+$scope.user.lastname)     
    }
});
```

Comment: even after adding above, it's showing undefined for $scope.user.lastname

Answer (score -1):

Of course!!! If you want the binding (HTML <--> JavaScript) you must respect the rules of Angular. What you need to do is to update the ng-model being defined for the input box. So, add to your input box: `ng-model="blabla"` and within your JavaScript: `$scope.blabla = <value>`.

Correction: You do have the ng-model in the input, but still miss the assignment within your javascript code.